# Unable to ping domain but can ping server

Tags: ping, debian-jessie

I setup a Virtual Server on Hetzner after [using this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/perfect-server-debian-8-jessie-apache-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3/3/). Everything was fine, no errors.

I setup ISP Config, added a domain `example.com`; vhost file is ok checked; DNS is declared.

But I have ping on server, no ping or DNS lookup on domain.
I do not what to do :

```
ping http://78.47.156.188/ ok ; 
ping domain noting
```

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to `ping`:

```
ping http://78.47.156.188/
```

Using `ping` is strictly an ICMP networking task; the `http://` is not useful here. It makes `ping` believe you are attempting to ping the full hostname of `http://78.47.156.188/` when the `http://` and trailing `/` are just URL protocol parts. You should be pinging like this:

```
ping 78.47.156.188
```

And for the hostname it should be like this:

```
ping example.com
```

Comment: But also, the domain name isn't a hostname unless it is defined to be one.  `example.com` might or might not map to the address of a host.  If the user has defined `www.example.com`, then he should ping that.  For example, `ping www.ibm.com` succeeds; `ping ibm.com` gets a different address and gets no response.